# how many assignable adresses are needed for a router to router connection?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I am trying to subnet an adress zone,optimally, with VLSM. I have a number of subnetworks, each with certain minimum needs for assignable adresses, and a couple of router to router connections, that I must consider as separate subnetworks. My question is(as stated in the title) how many adresses are needed for a router to router connection(that is considered as a subnetwork)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the router-to-router connection must be a subnet (contrasted with a point-to-point connection), the smallest subnet you can use is /30.

```
NET.0 - network address
NET.1 - first router
NET.2 - other router
NET.3 - broadcast address
```

So, if you were using 192.0.2.64/30, for example, your addresses would be:

```
192.0.2.64 - network address
192.0.2.65 - router
192.0.2.66 - router
192.0.2.67 - broadcast
```